# Woo - How move total price in checkout under delivery row

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I need to move the total price below the submit order button. I edited the code directly in the woocommerce plugin, but with every update this file was overwritten. Does anyone have a code that will help me make this change.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find such a solution and I'm not sure if I'm phrasing it correctly.

Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: You need to create a child theme and modify woocommerce using a child theme. Here is a simple blog on how you do it. https://www.godaddy.com/garage/how-to-override-woocommerce-template-files/

You can search on the internet **how to make a child theme in WordPress** and **how to customize a woocommerce template using a child theme**. there are many articles available on these topics

Comment: You probably don't necessarily need to create a child theme. The WooCommerce templates are full of hooks, so usually this would be done by "un-hooking" the functionality that outputs the total price from its current location, and then adding it in the one where you want this to appear.